# How to combine three tables result by one SQL query

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables

```
TABLE "TUTOR"
TUTOR_ID   NMAE   
---------------
1          N1
2          N2
3          N3
4          N4

TABLE "TUTOR_SETTING"
TUTOR_ID   MAX_STU_NUM
----------------------
1          5 
2          6

TABLE "STU_TUTOR_MAPPING"
----------------------
STU_ID   TUTOR_ID
A         1
B         2
C         1
D         1
```

and I want to combile below 3 sql into ONE SQL:

```
1. SELECT * FROM TUTOR t1
2. SELECT * FROM TUTOR_SETTING t2 where t2.TUTOR_ID=t1.TUTOR_ID
3. SELECT COUNT(t3.STU_ID) FROM STU_TUTOR_MAPPING t3 WHERE t3.TUTOR_ID=t1.TUTOR_ID GROUP BY T1.TUTOR_ID
```

and expected result:
select all from table "TUTOR" and JOIN "TUTOR_SETTING" and join "STU_TURTOR_MAPPING" and also count the rows of "STU_TUTOR_MAPPING" when there have same tutor_id.

```
TUTOR_ID    NAME     MAX_STU_NUM    TOTAL_STU_NUM
-------------------------------------------------
1           N1       5              3
2           N2       6              1
3           N3       null
4           N4       null
```

I tried this way:

```
SELECT t1.TUTOR_ID, t1.NAME, t2.MAX_STU_NUM, count(t3.STU_ID)
FROM TUTOR t1
   LEFT JOIN TUTOR_SETTING t2 on (t1.TUTOR_ID=t2.TUTOR_ID)
   LEFT JOIN stu_tutor_mapping t3 on (t1.TUTOR_ID=t3.TUTOR_ID)
GROUP BY t1.TUTOR_ID, t1.NAME;
```

but the database report a error:

```
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 30
```

Finally, I resolve this issue by google, here is the sql statement:

```
SELECT t1.TUTOR_ID, t1.NAME, t2.MAX_STU_NUM, t3.stu_allocated
FROM TUTOR t1
   LEFT JOIN TUTOR_SETTING t2 on (t1.TUTOR_ID=t2.TUTOR_ID)
   LEFT JOIN 
   (select tutor_id ,count(*) as TOTAL_STU_NUM from stu_turtor_mapping group by 
   tutor_id) t3 on t3.TUTOR_ID=t1.TUTOR_ID
```

Comment: Which RDBMS? What's your desired output? What have you tried?

Comment: You want to Join this tables or how do you expect result from this

Comment: It's ORACLE express Database, and I want to query table "TUTOR" and JOIN "TUTOR_SETTING" and join "STU_TURTOR_MAPPING" and also count the rows of "STU_TUTOR_MAPPING" when there have same tutor_id.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  a.Tutor_ID,
        a.Name,
        COUNT(b.TUTOR_ID) TotalCount
FROM    Tutor a
        LEFT JOIN STU_TUTOR_MAPPING b
            ON a.Tutor_ID = b.TUTOR_ID
GROUP   BY a.Tutor_ID, a.Name
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

The query above will display all records from table `TUTOR` whether it has no matching record on the other table and will display `0` as the total count since it is using `LEFT JOIN`. If you want to list all records where it has atleast 1 matching record on the other table, `INNER JOIN` will suffice.

```
SELECT  a.Tutor_ID,
        a.Name,
        COUNT(*) TotalCount
FROM    Tutor a
        INNER JOIN STU_TUTOR_MAPPING b
            ON a.Tutor_ID = b.TUTOR_ID
GROUP   BY a.Tutor_ID, a.Name
```

Comment: Thanks JW, I want to combine 3 tables , means there should have two LEFT JOINS one is to JOIN TABLE "TUTOR_SETTING" and another to JOIN TBALE "STU_TUTOR_MAPPING" ant it's ROWS

Answer (score 1):

Its so simple use Join on your query.
If you are not aware about JOIN then [Link 1.](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp),[Link 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)

Comment: I would give this +1 if the reference wasn't to w3schools, one of the worst reference sites of the internet.

Comment: @JanHudec you are right.But its very primary.So I just shared this ref.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way -

```
SELECT t1.TUTOR_ID, t1.NAME, t2.MAX_STU_NUM, count(t3.stu_id)
FROM TUTOR t1
   LEFT JOIN TUTOR_SETTING t2 on (t1.TUTOR_ID=t2.TUTOR_ID)
   LEFT JOIN STU_TUTOR_MAPPING t3 on (t1.TUTOR_ID=t3.TUTOR_ID)
GROUP BY t1.TUTOR_ID, t1.NAME, t2.MAX_STU_NUM
```

Comment: I tried but it report a error:ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 30

Comment: please see my updated answer... i have changed query to use `count(t3.stu_id)`